# How to switch between light and dark mode with water.css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the water.css in my website and I have this js code:

```
function setTheme(themeName) {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
    document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}
// function to toggle between light and dark theme
function toggleTheme() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
        setTheme('theme-light');
    } else {
        setTheme('theme-dark');
    }
}
// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function () {
   if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
      setTheme('theme-dark');
   } else {
      setTheme('theme-light');
   }
})();
```

and this button to switch:

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Theme Switcher</h1>
        <button id="switch" onclick="toggleTheme()">Switch</button>
    </div>
```

I import the javascript file and I wanted to know how I can change the javascript code to switch between 2 cdn links:

1. dark.min.css

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css">`

and
2. water.css

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/light.min.css">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can change the theme:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Theme Switcher</h1>
      <button id="switch" onclick="toggleTheme()">Switch</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

javacript

```
function setTheme(themeName) {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);

  //document.documentElement.className = themeName;

  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  if (themeName == "theme-dark") {
    link.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css';
  } else {
    link.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/light.min.css';
  }
  document.head.appendChild(link);
}

// function to toggle between light and dark theme
function toggleTheme() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
    setTheme('theme-light');
  } else {
    setTheme('theme-dark');
  }
}

// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
    setTheme('theme-dark');
  } else {
    setTheme('theme-light');
  }
})();
```

The changes I made are in `setTheme` function:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  if (themeName == "theme-dark") {
    link.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css';
  } else {
    link.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/light.min.css';
  }
  document.head.appendChild(link);
```

This adds the relevant *css* based on your theme.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/x2bchqyj/) is a JSFiddle live demo.

Comment: it doesnt save the  theme when the user clicks the back button.

Comment: @Liel I have tested it and It does save the theme, there must be some other issue.